# How to override the public images directory in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

/cake/config/paths.php

/**
 * Path to the public images directory.
 */
    define('IMAGES', WWW_ROOT.'images'.DS);

/**
 * Web path to the public images directory.
 */
if (!defined('IMAGES_URL')) {
    define('IMAGES_URL', 'images/');
}

How do I override the above constants that are set in /cake/config/paths.php ?  Would I set them in /app/config/bootstrap.php ?  If so, what is the correct syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how you want to use them.

If you're keeping images somewhere else and want to use the html->image helper, you can specify a new location relative to root simply by prepending a /directory, viz:

```
echo $html->image('/myImages/face.jpg');
```